# Vueling not allowing me to check in online

Tags: eu-citizens, barcelona, vueling

I’ve got a flight from London to Barcelona coming up and I’ve just tried checking in online but was told that because of my nationality I would have to check in at the airport. I have a EU passport and never had this happen with any other airline, my boyfriend has a UK passport and his seemed to work fine. I don’t understand why I wouldn’t be permitted to check in online holding a EU passport flying from the UK to Spain? I’ve traveled to spain numerous times using different airlines and never had this issue, also cannot find any type of information online about this.

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/173969/online-check-in-not-permitted-due-to-my-nationality ?

Comment: Is your passport from a Schengen Area country?

Comment: Did you get an explanation at the airport when you travelled? I am in the same situation now. Flying tomorrow from Gatwick to Gran Canaria. Please let me know what are the options. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Low-cost airlines (Ryanair, Vueling, Wizzair, *et al*, are well-known for being fussy about check-in, sometimes requiring additional steps or even the presentation of documents that don't seem to be required.

This behavior may be a function of their low-cost-ness, with staff being overly careful to avoid putting the airline in a situation where the airline must return the passenger to the departing airport because of a perceived or even possible refusal of entry at the arrival airport.

Whatever the reason, if you want to fly on those airlines (and take advantage of their low fares) you'll have to do what they require. Here, that's an in-person check-in.

Comment: OP could also try stating that they have a UK passport, there's a 99% chance they'd be able to check-in online and still be allowed to board. See: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/119007/as-of-2018-does-ryanair-deny-boarding-to-non-eu-passengers-who-skip-the-landsid